# How do I prevent the scale labels from being cut off in chartjs?

Tags: chart.js

I am having a problem with [chartjs](http://chartjs.org) where the scale labels are being "cut off" in the following way:

[image: cut off][1]

Is there a margin that can be set?  I don't see anything in the chartjs documentation about this, and these seem to be contained within the chartjs canvas element (meaning: not covered by another div).

Comment: which version are you using as i thought they fixed this? version 1.0.1 beta 4 should have this. If it isn;t fixed can you display the code you use to create and display the graph

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Add scale label option with whitespace before `value`. 2 or more whitespaces is allowed.

```
scaleLabel: "<%= ' ' + value%>"
```

Comment: What a dumb solution, but you know what?  this is the only thing that works that I've found.  Upvote.

Comment: @AndreiZhamoida Hey but y-axis for horizontal bar chart still getting cut off if the label is too long. By any chance, is there any way to make the label multiline?

Comment: Where does this go, i tried it under yAxes but that didnt work

Comment: @ChrisJamesChampeau there were some changes since my answer :). Since v2.0.0(I suppose) they've implemented `ticks`. Regarding the http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html?h=scalelabel you should use `ticks` callback option for text manipulating.

Answer (score 22):

You can also set a padding in the layout configuration (in chart.js 2 at least):

```
options: {
    layout: {
        padding: {
            left: 10
        }
    }
}
```

http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/layout.html

Comment: Works for me! Tks

Comment: Thanks man! Is there also a way to make it more dynamic instead of using pixels? I have an idea of getting char length of the legend texts and adjusting accordingly, but it seems overkill...

Comment: I guess you can do it every time the chart is updated (maybe using options.animations.onComplete or a tooltip callback), and using the chart dimensions from the chart object... But for my use case it was just easier to use a padding with some extra pixels so that I'm almost sure that the labels will always fit

Comment: In the current version this ads padding to the whole chart container. It does not change the size or position of the label box inside the chart, which seems to be the problem if the label is to short and cut of.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my hack - was scratching my head for a while until I found this post - thanks Jean-Baptiste Martin - your code lead me to this...

Given a dataset like [201, 203, 20004, etc.] - I grab the biggest and get length. 7 padding per character seems to work for me. length - 1 is to subtract 1 since the first character shows up fine for me - only need to add padding for all the other characters lopped off.

Hacky but this seems to work (on v 2.8) - I tested numbers up to like 40854385394 down to just single digits and it good enough for me!

```
options: {
  layout: { padding: { left: (this.data.reduce((a, b) => a > b ? a : b).toString().length - 1) * 7 } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of chart.js may have changed since this questions was originally posted. With v2.9.3, I only see this problem if the y-axis ticks include a mixture of integer & floating-point values. In this case (unfortunately my predominant case), the digits past the decimal point get clipped.

Below is what worked for me. In my solution, when there *is* a mixture of int & float, I just set a constant amount of padding (30px) to accommodate the floating-point digits; you may need a different value. Hopefully this helps some other soul avoid a day of struggle.

```
yAxes: [
    {
        ...
        ticks: {
            callback: (value, index, label_values) => {
                // Once per cycle through all the ticks, set the label padding appropriately
                // For unknown reasons sometimes chartjs passes a 1-point values array, which has no meaning. Ignore those.
                if (label_values.length > 1 && value === label_values[0]) {
                    // If labels have mixture of int & float, manually set the padding to give enough space for the decimal places.
                    const mixed_int_and_float_labels = label_values.some(v => Number.isInteger(v)) && !label_values.every(v => Number.isInteger(v));
                    this.chart.options.layout.padding.left = mixed_int_and_float_labels ? 30 : 0;
                }
                return value;
            }
        },
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same problem while creating a horizontal bar graph, I followed @Andrei Zhamoida's answers and looked up at the Chart.JS documentation regarding **ticks**.

Here's my solution:

```
scales: {
    y: {
        ticks: {
            callback: function (val, index) {
                return '   ' + this.getLabelForValue(val);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Documentation: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html?h=scalelabel

Comment: This worked for me but didn't have to use `getLabelForValue()`, the spaces and `val` by itself were enough.

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario I was having the far right label on the x axis getting cut off.
What fixed my case was adjusting layout padding.

```
layout: {
    padding: {
         right: 20
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was with setting up `sampleSize` which I used to make the chart rendering faster.

```
scales: {
  y: {
    ticks: {
      sampleSize:1 
    }
  }
}
```

This option sets the number of elements (in this example for the `y` axis) to calculate the space for ticks and when for example the first number is `5` and second `10`, then there will not be enough space for `10`

From docs (**chartjs v3.6**):

> The number of ticks to examine when deciding how many labels will fit. Setting a smaller value will be faster, but may be less accurate when there is large variability in label length.