# How to stop axis label from being cut off in chart JS?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

How do I stop the chart from cutting off the axis label words? This question is similar: "[How do I prevent the scale labels from being cut off in chartjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26498171/how-do-i-prevent-the-scale-labels-from-being-cut-off-in-chartjs)" But only addresses the labels on the tick marks.

The axis label should say "mental health continuum". But the `m` is cut off.

[image: Chart cut off]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix that by setting the layout padding on the chart.

```
options: {
  layout: {
    padding: {
      top: 20
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the reference
http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/layout.html